# Async/await don't work in Google Chrome mobile

Tags: javascript

I'm learning to work with async and I'm testing compatibility with old iphones, i'm using google chrome of iphone 5s which is on version 92.0.4515 but i noticed that async doesn't work, is there any correct way or is it not available in old versions?

```js
// Main.js
export async function hello(){
  alert("Hello " + navigator.userAgent)
}

// index.html
(async function(){
  const start = await import('./main.js');
  start.hello();
})();
```

Comment: IPhone browsers are just thin wrappers around Safari web views last I checked.

Comment: `google chrome of iphone 5s` is just safari

Comment: What ios version do you have installed, that will tell you the version of Safari.

Comment: Look into transpiling your code with babel to make it work in older browsers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await says that async/await keywords have had safari support since iOS 10. Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: Is dynamic imports even supported by this version?

Comment: @zero298 - 12.5.4

Comment: Even safari on iOS 11 supports dynamic imports.

Comment: @Dominik great!!

Comment: @evolutionxbox All right, thanks